# how to update the files saved in registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have saved an xml file in Configuration registry `/_system/config/test.xml`. My xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition>
<Source1001>Endpoint1</Source1001>
<Source1002>Endpoint2</Source1002>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Now can i create a proxy to update the contents of the above xml file by use of sequence or class mediator? If i pass new endpoint= Endpoint3 and Node = Source1001 in the request of the proxy. then for the node Source1001 i should be able to see the changed endpoint as Endpoint3

Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No built-in mediator can do this. You can write a class mediator to read the xml placed in registry, then save it after editing. You have to get the reference to registry service via osgi at the class mediator for that. 
FYI. you can get the input from message context and find the values to replace.

Comment: can you share a sample example of class mediator regarding above problem?

Answer (score 0):

This [1] post explains about creating class mediator to read from registry resource. Hope this will be helpful during your task.

[1] http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/02/accessing-registry-resources-from-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code segment within a class mediator or you can do the same with script mediator as well.

```
mc.getConfiguration().getRegistry().updateResource(
            resourcePath, mc.getProperty("myProperty").toString().getBytes());
```

You can find more details on how to use either one of those mediators [here](http://asitha.github.io/cs/programming/gotchas/wso2/2015/09/03/save-content-into-wso2-registry-through-mediators/)